2024-05-17 15:26:32,216:ERROR:flask_appbuilder.api:'GuestUser' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
While creating dashboard api using the guest token, I am facing this issue.
Last point from which superset is throwing the error is:

File "/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/superset/daos/base.py", line
151, in create
db.session.add(item)

And the originating error is:

File
"/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py",
line 2049, in 
((c is not None) and instance_state(c) or None, c)
Error 2024-05-17 15:26:32,216:ERROR:flask_appbuilder.api:'GuestUser'
object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Looks like this is related to sqlalchemy. Any suggestions anyone?
